# Perform Python socket module operations like gethostbyname() / getFQDN() on multiple items in a List and skip specific items in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sockets

Using Python socket modele, I am trying to perform dns resolution check on multiple items from a list and skip some items in between.

The below lines of code works fine, however if there is an incorrect URL in between, say instead of wwww.bing.com, if I put [www.biiiiinnnnggggg.com](http://www.biiiiinnnnggggg.com), the code just stops there and doesn't continue to [www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com).

How do I skip an invalid URL from this list and go ahead with remaining items in the list incase of any errors with one of them in between.

```
import socket
a=["www.google.com", "www.bing.com", "www.microsoft.com"]
for b in a:
  print(socket.gethostbyname(b))
  print(socket.getfqdn(b)+"\n")
```

Comment: Are you receiving any type of error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.